# How do i write more complex code in Lotus Notes views

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

i currently work on a project where i have to write a programm which processes raw data from a
Notes Database into an excel file using Lotus Script. The Database contains time information about how long different devices have been lend out. The output from my script looks like this:

| June |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Device | Counter | Times(Minutes) | Times(Hours) |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| TestDevice1 | 3 | 270 | 4,5 |
| TestDevice2 | 2 | 210 | 3,5 |

I am finished with the programm itself, now i need to have the same Output inside a Lotus notes View. I am very new to lotus notes and i have no idea how to do this. I know that it is possible to use Lotus Formula to programm. But i cant find anything about the language and how to use it. Maybe someone here can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the online documentation provided by HCL ["About Designing Views"](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_ABOUT_DESIGNING_VIEWS.html)

Pay particular attention to "Selecting which documents display in a view" and "Creating columns in a view" (and its subsection "
Adding programming to columns").

That should give you a few ideas of how to progress.

Comment: One word of warning, a common Notes newbie mistake is to use \@Now or \@Today in a view column formula (especially in cases like yours where you want to show "How long since....")  Don't make that mistake, learn how to do it properly.  (Hint: Create a scheduled agent that updates a field on the documents in the background.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get close.

Make a view to display the Device, Counter, Times, and Times columns, unsorted.

Once you figure that out, create a new column that displays the month. (Hint: See @Text formula.)

Now change it to subcategorized by month by changing the month column to be the first column, and then edit the column properties to give it a width of 1 or 2, not resizable, and make it a category column with twisties shown.

This will get you close. Instead of the month followed by column titles followed by the data, you will get column titles followed by the month followed by the data per month.

Comment: You might also need to also insert two hidden columns prior to your category column, sorted, with formulas of `@Year(YourDateField)` and `@Month(YourDateField)` so that April isn't sorted before January.

Comment: I will try this, Thanks !