# Is there a way to filter information from a view and display them in the same view?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

two months ago i asked this Question: [How do i write more complex code in Lotus Notes views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70166547/how-do-i-write-more-complex-code-in-lotus-notes-views).
My View now looks like this:

| Year | Month | Device | Counter | Times(Minutes) | Times(Hours) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | January |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Test 01 |  | 270 | 4,5 |
|  |  | Test 02 |  | 210 | 3,5 |
|  |  | Test 01 |  | 60 | 1 |
|  |  | Test 01 |  | 90 | 1,5 |
|  | February |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Test 01 |  | 30 | 0,5 |
|  |  | Test 02 |  | 180 | 3 |
|  |  | Test 01 |  | 60 | 1 |

The Database sets a new Document every time a Device is lend out. What i want to do now is to read trough every document and combine  "Times(Minutes)" and "Times(Hours)" inside an variable, and also save each device name one time.When a device name is scanned more then once, the counter will go up by one. In my Lotus script program i did this using a Multi-Dimensional Array.

I Want to do this because i want to display each Device only **One** Time. Then each device has the combined values inside the "Times" Columns, and a counter to show how often the Device has been lend out in the chosen month. It should look like this:

| Year | Month | Device | Counter | Times(Minutes) | Times(Hours) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | January |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Test 01 | 3 | 420 | 7 |
|  |  | Test 02 | 1 | 210 | 3,5 |
|  | Feburary |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Test 01 | 2 | 90 | 1,5 |
|  |  | Test 02 | 1 | 180 | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the device column to be categorised, and set totals on the Times columns properties, this will give you what you want.  It will have the benefit that you can also see the total times across the month for all devices before you drill down

Comment: Thanks ! That nearly solved it, my only problem is that setting totals wont work for me , the Times colums use multiple variables from the database, which also store the date, because of that i have some code inserted into the columns, it looks like this : ` time := (((@Hour(EndTime)*60)+@Minute(EndTime))-((@Hour(StartTime)*60)+@Minute(StartTime))); @Text(time) `  If i try using the totals setting it just shows 0

Comment: You can create a hidden computed field on the form you use.  Put that formula in.  Refresh the documents.  Change the column to display the new computed field value instead of the formula and your totals will show properly.  It will also make your views a little faster by removing all of the calculation from them.

Comment: Tried to edit my previous comment, but too much time had lapsed.  Try taking off the @Text() that surrounds the time variable at the end of your formula.  Totals need to be on number columns.